# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable in python module tinydb

Tags: python, database

I have error TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable, when try to use function **search** in tinydb

My code:

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
db = TinyDB('db.json')
User = Query()
db.insert({'test': 'signs', 'age': 34})
res = db.search(User.test == 'signs')
print(res)
```

`

Comment: Looks like this is either not the entire code or you haven't saved it before running it. If you used some examples from internet before, the chances are high that you used some assigment to some variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that "test" is a [built-in function](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=.query()#tinydb.queries.Query.test) for a Query object.
Changing `test` to `name` or anything else will fix issue.

```
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
db = TinyDB('db.json')
User = Query()
db.insert({'name': 'signs', 'age': 34})
res = db.search(User.name == "signs")
print(f"the search: {res}")
print(f"User.test: {User.test}")
```

##### Output

```
the search: [{'name': 'signs', 'age': 34}]
User.test: <bound method Query.test of Query()>
```

You can also see 'test' listed as an attribute of a `Query` object buy running `dir()` on the object you create

```
>>> from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
>>> User = Query()
>>> dir(User)
['__and__', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__or__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_generate_test', '_hash', '_path', '_test', 'all', 'any', 'exists', 'fragment', 'is_cacheable', 'map', 'matches', 'noop', 'one_of', 'search', 'test']
```